# How to insert XML into Oracle database?

Tags: java, xml, oracle

I'm trying to insert XML into Oracle database same as it appears in the saved RandomQuestions.xml file, I'm not getting any error as such
but this is how it appears in database, I have QUESTIONS data type as VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE);

if I use ByteArrayOutputStream, In database it appears like this:-

```
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@38d21a74
```

without use of ByteArrayOutputStream:-

```
javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult@7138a214
```

RandomQuestions.xml looks like this:-

```
<GeneratedSet genBy="Tony Bond" genDate="23/01/2018">
    <Questions Level="1" NumQuestions="5" Type="Addition">
        <Question Answer="6.0" Text="5.0 + 1.0"/>
        <Question Answer="12.0" Text="9.0 + 3.0"/>
        <Question Answer="12.0" Text="5.0 + 7.0"/>
        <Question Answer="13.0" Text="8.0 + 5.0"/>
        <Question Answer="10.0" Text="3.0 + 7.0"/>
    </Questions>
</GeneratedSet>
```

My Code:-

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    some code here ....

    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        // root elements
        Document doc = db.newDocument();

       some code here ...

        StringBuffer retXML = new StringBuffer("<GeneratedSet  genDate='").append(ft.format(todayDate)).append("' genBy='").append(userName).append("'>");

        if (add != null) {
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            genMaths gm = new genMaths();
            retXML.append(gm.additionQ(leve, 2, numOfQuesAdd, 1));
        }
        retXML.append("</GeneratedSet>");
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(retXML.toString()));
        doc = db.parse(is);

        DOMSource source1 = new DOMSource(doc);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\XML Files\\RandomQuestions.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        /************** Adding questions to database **************/

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source, result);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

        try {
            dbConn = new DbConnection();
            conn = DbConnection.connection();
            CallableStatement proc = null;
            proc = conn.prepareCall("{call pa_customer_admin.pr_create_question(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

            proc.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(assId));
            proc.setString(2, qusTypeCode);
            proc.setString(3, inputStream.toString());
            proc.setString(4, mark);
            proc.setString(5, timeLimit);
            proc.setString(6, cdocId);
            proc.registerOutParameter(7, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
            proc.registerOutParameter(8, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            proc.execute();

            String errorMessage = proc.getString(8);
            if (errorMessage == null) {
                System.out.println("No Error");
                quesId = proc.getString(7);
            } else {
                System.out.println(" Error : " + errorMessage);
            }
            proc.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage() + "error Code : " + e.getErrorCode());
        } catch (NumberFormatException | ServletException | IOException e) {


        System.out.println("File saved!");

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    } catch (SAXException | TransformerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(XmlServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there some reason you want to store this as bytes? or is straight up XML fine?

Comment: It has to be bytes because some other data is being stored in there which is not  xml.

Comment: AFAIK, these files should be saved as BLOB.